# show / hide submit button

Tags: jquery, button, submit

HOWTO?

show submit button only if one or two needed inputs are filled with a value
but if you remove on of the needed values, the submit has to disappear.

should be done with keyup i think.
any idea?

Comment: Not too sure about this, but if you hide the submit button and hit enter, will the form still post?  You'd be better validating the form on submit, rather than trying to block the submit altogether.

Comment: @Paddy: You're right. If 'Enter' is pressed the form will still post even if the fields are left blank. I have edited my answer below to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function below should help you out:

```
$(function(){
    // Hide submit button if either field is empty
    $('form input').keyup(function(){
        if($('#input1').val() == "" || $('input2').val() == ""){
            $('#submit').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#submit').show();
        }
    });
    // Don't submit form if either field is empty
    $('form').submit(function(){
    if($('#1').val() == "" || $('#2').val() == ""){
        return false;
    }
    });
});
```

By the way, you'll need to use CSS (`display:none`) to hide your submit button initially.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use one event handler at the form itself and to check all required fields. To keep it a little bit more abstractive, it would be nice if you can tag your inputs with some attribute. The example solution follows:

```
    $('#formNode').keyup(function(e){
            var invalid = false;
            $(this).children().each(function(i,child){  
                if(($(child).attr("isReq") == "true") 
                    && child.value.length == 0
                ){
                    invalid = true;
                }   
            });
            $("#submitButton")[invalid ? "hide" : "show"]();
});   




    <form id="formNode">
            <input type="text" isReq="true"/>
        <input type="text" isReq="true"/>
        <input type="text" isReq="true"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" id="submitButton"/>
    </form>
```

As you can see, every time you want to check node, you just should mark it with attribute isReq and the script will do its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Without reference in basic javascript:**

```
<input type="text" id="input-1" onkeyup="submitChange();" />

<input type="text" id="input-2" onkeyup="submitChange();" />

<input type="submit" id="submit" style="display: none;" />

<script type="text/javascript">

inputOne = document.getElementById("input-1"); 
inputTwo = document.getElementById("input-2"); 
inputSubmit = document.getElementById("submit"); 

function submitChange()
{
     if(inputOne.value == "" || inputTwo.value == "")
     {
          inputSubmit.style.display = "none";
     }
     else
     {
          inputSubmit.style.display = "block";
     }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Since he said two, I made a script which handles two

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inputid').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
       $('#submitbutton').show();
    } else {
       $('#submitbutton').hide();
    }
});
```

for multiple:

```
$('#inputid1,#inputid2, etc...').keyup(function() {
   var hidden = false;
   $('#inputid1,#inputid2, etc...').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
          hidden = true;
      }
   })
   if (hidden) {
      $('#submitbutton').hide();
   } else {
      $('#submitbutton').show();
   }
```

});

Comment: Of course, but since the poster tagged the question with jquery, I figured that was alright.

Comment: My mistake, forgot to check tags :P

Comment: Rather than $('#input1,#input2,...') you could use the form as a container, $('#formName > :input'), or just select all the textboxes, $(':input'), if they all are part of the form.

Comment: Yeah, or add a class to all required fields and use $('input.required').

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a look at the `onblur`.

[onblur Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

> The onblur event occurs when an object
>   loses focus.

Comment: Cause it's more user friendly when you activate button when input field is not empty. Otherwise you do not give enough response to the user and he/she thinks, that form is still disabled.

Comment: The onblur event can use java script to check the required fields, and *enable/disable* the button as required.

Comment: I mean, response from form is only visible when you leave the input field. This means, that at the moment of typing user still "in panic" why his form button is disabled.

Comment: Onblur requires the user to tab/click out of the element before the function is fired. Could prove annoying for the end user in this scenario.